# Merge key and value into an array in Twig file

Tags: php, symfony, twig-extension

I want to add key and value into array in twig file. But I am facing following issue `"Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string or a number"`

```
{% set phoneCount = 0 %}
{% set phoneNumbers = {} %}
{% for currPhone in currBroker.phones %}
    {% if (currPhone.type == 'Work' or currPhone.type == 'Mobile') and phoneCount <= 2 and currPhone.number !='' %}
        {% set phoneCount = phoneCount + 1 %}                   
        {% set phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers|merge({ currPhone.type:currPhone.type }) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ phoneNumbers|print_r }}
```

I just need the syntax of merging key and value into array. 
I tried by giving static inputs and its works

```
{% set phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers|merge({ 'work':'(011)112-1233' }) %}
```

But its not working for dynmic input. Please help!!

Comment: A useful rule of thumb is to create a twig extension any time you need to apply some display logic beyond very simple if statements. Even if you got it to work with twig, it's not worth the effort needed to maintain it. {% set phoneNumbers = currBroker.phones | extract_phone_numbers %} will save you many headaches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to wrap your key in braces :

```
{% set phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers|merge({ (currPhone.type) : currPhone.type }) %}
```

Tested and working example :

```
{% set currPhone = {type: 'test'} %}
{% set phoneNumbers = {} %}
{% set phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers|merge({ (currPhone.type) : currPhone.type }) %}
{% dump(phoneNumbers) %}
```

I get :

```
array:1 [▼
  "test" => "test"
]
```

Comment: Not working. Showing error: Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string or a number (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "("

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example. No problem on my side with that code.