# Remove duplicate data from the Twig object and combine it

Tags: php, twig

In my **Twig template** i have list, something like this:

```
1985 - John
1974 - Lena
1985 - Sandra
1974 - Tom
1985 - Jess
```

The year can be duplicated. So i need combine my list like this:

```
1985 - John, Sandra, Jess
1974 - Lena, Tom
```

Is it possible to do this in the Twig template engine?

Comment: What is the source of the data? It may be easier to do this with PHP, before passing the data to Twig.

Comment: I don't have access to the php-code

Comment: Do the input array has keys? Like `{"year": 1985, "name": "John"}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge key and value into an array in Twig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137739/merge-key-and-value-into-an-array-in-twig-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twig, we can add data to an array with the [`merge`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/merge.html) filter.

The tricky parts:

- we have to merge the names for each year **and then** merge it to the main array, with the year as the key
- Twig resets the key to a number (`0`, `1`, etc.) if we try to use a number as a key

If we have this data:

```
{% set data = [
  {"year": 1985, "name": "John"},
  {"year": 1974, "name": "Lena"},
  {"year": 1985, "name": "Sandra"},
  {"year": 1974, "name": "Tom"},
  {"year": 1985, "name": "Jess"},
]
%}
```

We can loop over it, and create an array, with each year as the key and the names as values:

```
{% set groupedData = {} %}

{# Loop over data #}

{% for person in data -%}
    {# the year must be casted as a string, otherwise it uses numeric keys in the array #}
    {% set year = "y" ~ person["year"] %}
    {% set name = person["name"] %}
  
    {% if year not in groupedData|keys %}
        {# year doesn't exist in the array, add a key with the year and an array with one name #}
        {% set groupedData = groupedData|merge({(year): [name]}) %}
    {% else %}
        {# year exists in the array, add the name to the array of names for this year #}
        {% set newNamesForYear = attribute(groupedData, year)|merge([name]) %}
        {% set groupedData = groupedData|merge({(year): newNamesForYear}) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And display the result:

```
{% for year, names in groupedData %}
    {# remove the y in the year and print the names #}
    {{ year|slice(1) }} - {{ names|join(', ') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the result:

```
1985 - John, Sandra, Jess
1974 - Lena, Tom
```

[Try it online on TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/8zrp0l).

Resources used:

- [Twig merge multiple things in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47598944/2257664)
- [Merge key and value into an array in Twig file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137978/2257664) (including [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137739/merge-key-and-value-into-an-array-in-twig-file/31137978#comment50296248_31137978))

Comment: Some extra reference about why you can't merge numeric indices can be found [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/789)